# Unable to Convert String To Date App crashes and showing outlet is nil

Tags: ios, swift

I am loading a views from nib and i am successfully loaded but first one is loaded perfect but in second view getting nil outlets. below is my code.

Set a global variable to loadview by default is is 0 and it is increase when i press next button.

User is struct here :

```
struct User {
static var quizIndexNo      =   0
}
```

This method is in my ViewController

```
let moptViewInstance    =   MOPT()
let rmkViewInstance     =   RMK()
```

getting view name from this array: 
    let viewName = ["MOPT","RMK"]

```
func loadQuizView(){

        if viewName[User.quizIndexNo] == "MOPT" {

            for views in vwOptionView.subviews {
                views.removeFromSuperview()
            }

            moptViewInstance.prepareScreenWithView(navigationController: UINavigationController(), viewSize: self.vwOptionView, viewController: self)

        } else if viewName[User.quizIndexNo] == "RMK" {

            for views in vwOptionView.subviews {
                views.removeFromSuperview()
            }
            rmkViewInstance.prepareScreenWithView(navigationController: UINavigationController(), viewSize: self.vwOptionView, viewController: self)

        }
}
```

// NIB View Classes

```
class MOPT: UIView {

@IBOutlet weak var btnPrevious: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var btnNext: UIButton!

var nibView: UIView!
var instanceOfQuizController : QuizCointroller!

func prepareScreenWithView(navigationController: UINavigationController, viewSize: UIView, viewController: UIViewController) {

    nibView = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("MOPT", owner: self, options: nil)?[0] as! UIView
    nibView.tag = 200
    var tempRect = nibView.frame
    print(tempRect)

    if User.quizIndexNo == 0 {
        btnPrevious.isHidden = true
    }

    if User.quizIndexNo == 0 {
        btnNext.setTitle("Test", for: .normal)
    }

    print("Index No is: \(User.quizIndexNo) and \(Sequence.totalQuizQuestionCout)")

    if User.quizIndexNo == Sequence.totalQuizQuestionCout - 1 {
        btnNext.setTitle("Submit", for: .normal)
    }

    instanceOfQuizController = viewController as! QuizCointroller

    tempRect =  CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: viewSize.bounds.width, height: viewSize.bounds.height)
    viewSize.addSubview(self.nibView)
    self.nibView.frame = tempRect

}

@IBAction func btnPrev(_ sender: UIButton) {
    User.quizIndexNo -= 1
    Sequence.instanceOfQuizControllerTest.previousButtonPressed()

}
// Next button will reload next view 
@IBAction func btnNext(_ sender: UIButton) {
    User.quizIndexNo += 1
   // here sequence is global variable of type ViewController
    Sequence.instanceOfQuizControllerTest.nextButtonPressed()


    }
}
```

Second NibView Class 
    class RMK: UIView {

```
@IBOutlet weak var btnPrevious: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var btnNext: UIButton!

var nibView: UIView!
var instanceOfQuizControllerTest : QuizCointroller!

func prepareScreenWithView(navigationController: UINavigationController, viewSize: UIView, viewController: UIViewController) {

    nibView = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("RMK", owner: self, options: nil)?[0] as! UIView
    nibView.tag = 200
    var tempRect = nibView.frame
    print(tempRect)

    if User.quizIndexNo == 1 {
        btnPrevious.isHidden = true //app is crashing here when i am trying to set title Button is showing nil
    }

    if User.quizIndexNo == 1 {
        btnNext.setTitle("Submit", for: .normal)
    }

    instanceOfQuizControllerTest = viewController as! QuizCointroller

    print("Quiz ViewController instatnce \(instanceOfQuizControllerTest)")
    tempRect =  CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: viewSize.bounds.width, height: viewSize.bounds.height)
    viewSize.addSubview(self.nibView)
    self.nibView.frame = tempRect

}

@IBAction func btnPrev(_ sender: UIButton) {
    User.quizIndexNo -= 1
    Sequence.instanceOfQuizControllerTest.previousButtonPressed()


}

@IBAction func btnNext(_ sender: UIButton) {

    print(instanceOfQuizControllerTest)

    User.quizIndexNo += 1
    Sequence.instanceOfQuizControllerTest.nextButtonPressed()


   }
}
```

Comment: Nil outlet is never about converting string to Date. More likely that you forgot to drag a control from Story Board to the view controller

Comment: The crash is not related to conversion its is most likely you have missed to lint an outlet in XIB or SB. 

Also local variables from second view might not be sustaining in memory till the time you try to access them, try maintaining a strong outlet from first view to second one.

Comment: i cross check many times all outlets are connected. but dont know where is the problem